# File reading IO

Tags: java, sorting, search, file-io

I have recently been struggling to make solid progress in this assignment. I am required to create a program that takes in a text file, and create output that produces each word in the text file, the amount of times that word appears, and the percentage of occurrences out of the whole file. Right now, my primary issue is reading in all of the values of a text file. I am trying to use an array list to store what I read. Part of the details include that character such as commas, periods, semicolons, colons, and exclamation points should be ignored. This is the full assignment:

> Write a program that reads an ordinary text file in order to construct
>   a list of words and the number of times each word occurs. When
>   complete, the output of the program to the console should be a table
>   with three columns: The word found. The number of times that the word
>   appears in the file. The proportion of occurrences that are found
>   (e.g. 2.17%).
>
> This table is in lexicographical order according the word found.
>   Punctuation marks (`,.;:!`) occur at the end of a word and should be
>   removed. Upper and lowercase should be ignored. Hyphenated words
>   should be treated as a single word.
>
> Example: For the text à Mary had a little lamb, little lamb
>
> a         1     14.29%
>
> had       1     14.29%
>
> little    2     28.57%
>
> lamb      2     28.57%
>
> mary      1     14.29%

So my question for those of you out there are:

1. How do I read in the words of a text file into an array list so that I can manipulate them in the desired fashion.
2. What would be an optimal way to count the amount of an occurrence in an array list, and the optimal way to sort it in lexicographical order.
3. I plan to use `printf` for organized looking output like the given example, is this an optimal solution?
4. For the third column of percentages, I plan to print out (the amount of occurrences of the word / [divided by] the total amount of words in the file + % [percent sign plain text]), is this an optimal solution?

Here is what I have so far, as stated before, I am only up to trying to get all of the words into the array, and I am currently using a text file with the example's text: "à Mary had a little lamb, little lamb".

```
public class fileInfo 
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("testFile.txt"));
        scan.useDelimiter(" ");
        ArrayList<String> aL = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            if(scan.next() == "." || scan.next() == ",")
            {
                continue;
            }
            aL.add(scan.next());
        }
        scan.close();

        System.out.println(aL);
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> constructArray(ArrayList<String>temp) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("testFile.txt"));
        temp = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            temp.add(scan.next());
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't complex, and there are tons of examples already out there.

Comment: I personally think it is far more complex than most text file in and outputs out there. I spent quite awhile attempting to find help on reading the words in, and ignoring those characters as mentioned. If it isn't complex, care to lend a hand?

Comment: I'm not helping you do something that takes all of 5 minutes of googling, especially when its homework.

Comment: I spent awhile searching for examples, I really couldn't find anything. Homework or not, guidance is appreciated, not ignorance.

Comment: I don't believe you. It seems like you spent more time writing all that irrelevant stuff in your question. Plus you are literally asking us to tell you all of the points that you are meant to learn on the assignment. And you think I'm the ignorant one because I know for a fact that there are thousands of examples of counting the frequency of tokens??? Give me a break.

Comment: Can you use regular expressions? If yes, read the file one line at a time, find words in the line using regex [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29), then use a [`TreeMap<String, AtomicInteger>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) created with a `TERTIARY` [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html).

Comment: Those four questions are the thoughts I wrote up on the assignment while brainstorming, I even posted the full assignment so nobody would assume this, I posted my code which is only outputting a blank array, I don't want help with code, I want help on HOW to do this. How is any of what I wrote irrelevant in any way? I did my best to thoroughly explain everything I thought of, and everything that is required here. You're ignorant for not taking in all of the information I wrote out here-- I can't count the tokens and get the input while ignoring those characters, that is my big issue. Get it?

Comment: Dan, what @redFIVE is talking about, is the slew of similar question that pop up if you search for "java count words file" on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+count+words+file) or [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+count+words+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Did you try searching?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the response. I can definitely use any regular kind of expression, but because it is not always going to be the same word being found, I don't think going that route would work out. (ie. can't search for single term "lamb" and get the amount in that way. Do you have any idea as to why my array list is not filling from my current code? A ton of the examples I have given a look at take this approach with the simple Scanner for receiving input into the list.

Comment: @Andreas and yes, I have indeed tried searching. I agree there are at least millions of things on inputting the files, but I could not find a single thing on ignoring the punctuational characters mentioned in the post while doing the inputting

Comment: Dan, "[regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)", not "a regular kind of expression".

Comment: @Andreas, its obvious he has zero intention of doing any research on his own. He won't even type what you said into google. This seriously has to be one of the most common 1st year programming assignments out there.

Comment: Regular expressions can help eliminate special character, or a simple find/replace can do that too. And the `Collator` I mentioned takes care of the *"lexicographical order"* and *"Upper and lowercase should be ignored"* mentioned in the assignment.

Comment: @Andreas ah, I had never heard of these before, I read through the page on regular expressions, I have never used the regex library that you mentioned, sounds a bit out of my league at the moment! I think I will be able to handle the sorting, I just wanted to get a little input on what would be a really good way to do it so that I could study on more advanced things. Trying to deviate from just what my curriculum teaches and learn a bit more.

Comment: @redFIVE I understand that people often make posts for people to get their homework done but in no way have I requested absolute answers, I am just seeking guidance on how to approach the problem, you can go ahead and assume I am one of those idiots, but I can assure you I have certainly searched everything from vague terms "java filling array with text file elements" to things such as "how to ignore characters when inputting via text file in java" -- I am just trying to break apart the issues I am having to come to a solution and understand what I'm doing.

Comment: You were literally told what to search for. Also, stop being so verbose, you write far too much text for what you are trying to say.

Comment: I disagree, you're just trying to assert some kind of dominance and be correct, I am just trying to get help, that's enough of this, I won't reply to you anymore, you do the same please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I read in the words of a text file into an array list so that I can manipulate them in the desired fashion.

You set the delimiter of the `Scanner` to split on whitespace and punctuation characters. The delimiter is a regular expression as defined by the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. You want pattern:

```
"[\\s,.;:!]+"
```

which means: One or more whitespace or punctuation characters.

> What would be an optimal way to count the amount of an occurrence in an array list, and the optimal way to sort it in lexicographical order

Use a [`TreeMap<String, Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or `TreeMap<String, AtomicInteger>`.

For a simple English text only solution, you can simply lowercase the letters (your example did).

A better implementation is to initialize the `TreeMap` with a [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) with a `TERTIARY` strength.

*FYI:* Your example is wrong, because `lamb` should be listed before `little`.

> I plan to use printf for organized looking output like the given example, is this an optimal solution?

It is an appropriate way.

> For the third column of percentages, I plan to print out (the amount of occurances of the word / [divided by] the total amount of words in the file + % [percent sign plain text]), is this an optimal solution?

It is an appropriate way, and likely the easiest. Just remember to multiply by 100 and to perform division using `double`, not `int`.

Comment: Thank you a ton for the response Andreas, I am going to research on the TreeMap that you mentioned so that I can implement it. I forgot to remove the delimeter before I made this post, as that was one of the things I had seen may be of help to ignore the characters I needed to ignore, and couldn't figure out how to get it working. Thanks so much for explaining all of that!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's homework, I'm not going to put the literal code, it would take me more time to explain it than searching a solution on Google.

I will give you some ideas instead, so you just have to search how to implement these ideas in Java.

1) Have a dynamic list of Strings where you will store all of the words.

2) Use BufferedReader's readLine() method to get every line from the file.

3) For each line, store all of his words to the step 1)'s String dynamic list.

Hint: You can use blank spaces to know when does a word end/start.

4) When you have all the words from the file stored in one dynamic list, implement some super-efficient method counting what you need to display on the output.
Hint: You can go erasing the actual word, so on the future list scannings will be shorter. Would be something like:

> int i,j;
>
> for(i = 0; i < word_list.length - 1; i++){
>
> ```
>   for(j = i + 1; j < word_list.length - 1; j++){     
>
>         if(word_list.get(i) == word_list.get(j)){
>
>                   numberOfAppearences++;
>                   word_list.erase(j);
>                   j--; //we have erased one element
>          }
>
>    }
> ```
>
> }

This would only show the number of appearences of one given word. You obviously have to adecuate this code to your needs.

If you want to make it more optimal, without having to duplicate the file data into your RAM, you could read the file char by char, until you find the first blank space, this would mean that the first word has ended, so you can have this word stored in a String, and then proceed reading chars until you find the next blank space, this would be the second word now you would compare word1 with word2, do your math, and keep reading chars to go with the third word, and so on. With this way you would only need two Strings, one for the current word and the other for the next ones.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This and what the comment below were among the type of responses I was really hoping for, thank you a ton, this does indeed help me out. I am going to research on the BufferedLine you mention, that sounds like it will help a lot!

Comment: I'm glad this helped! So if this was what you were looking for please vote my answer up and accep it :)